# Regex to cut a Polynomial to parts

Tags: java, regex, string

I've been using the following regex : "(?=[+-])") with the split function to cut a polynomial but now it appears I'm supposed to also deal with polynomials of the following type a/-bx^n it worked well with the minus being before the a, but now it doesn't work with the minus being before the b.

I'd love some help to make it work.

Comment: Try `(?=[+-])(?!(?<=/)(?=-))`

Comment: I would suggest that you first write down a grammar to describe how a polynomial is constructed. That will then help you write a parser.  Depending solely on regexps may not be the best way to go.